# Angular2 Getting Value Of Switch

Tags: angular

**Background**

I have a few `switches` from [CoreUI](http://coreui.io/docs/new-components/switches) in my `app` that `toggle` `on` and `off`. I need to be able to read the current `state` of these `switches`, "`on`" or "`off`". I also need to be able to set the `state` of them based on some other factors.

**Question**

I have not been able to find an example of this anywhere. How can I access the `switch` to obtain the current `state` and `set` the `state` to either `on` or `off`?

**Code Example**

```
   <label class="switch switch-text switch-pill switch-success switch-sm pull-right">
       <input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" checked>
       <span class="switch-label" data-on="On" data-off="Off"></span>
       <span class="switch-handle"></span>
    </label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="mySwitch">
<div> switch on: {{mySwitch}}</div>
```

```
class MyComponent {
  mySwitch: boolean = true;

}
```

Comment: Hey man I think I misunderstood your answer. It made sense when I read it but how does this add the checked attribute based on the boolean? Notice inside the input at the end of it in the example checked. Checked value exist when it is switched on. Would you still handle this in the same way?

Comment: If `mySwitch` is `true` (as it is in my example) then `ngModel` will assign that to `<input type="checkbox">`. `[(...)]="..."` is two-way-binding.

Comment: Wow ya great thanks man. How do you always know everything? It never ceases to amaze me.